# R Diagram display

Tags: r

I'm beginner with R 
How can I display same this diagram in R and what do they call it ?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be useful for you.

```
## creating a matrix
> data_frame <- matrix(c(0.8,0.2,0.7,0.3),2,2)
> data_frame
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.8  0.7
[2,]  0.2  0.3

## setting the dimension names
> dimnames(data_frame) <- list(c('Handwash','No Handwash'),c('Female','Male'))

## plotting the data

barplot(data_frame,col=rep(c('orange','skyblue'),ncol(data_frame)),legend.text = dimnames(data_frame)[[1]],ylab='Frequency')
```

[image]